# Question unanswerable (unreproducable), what do I do?

Tags: support

I had an unexpected result (a certain generated mail being considered spam) and as such, I set out to to find a way to prevent this from happening again. Finally I ended up on superuser and asked the question why it was happening.

However, now it is not happening anymore... even using the exact same details I cannot reproduce the problem.

What should I do here (or in similar cases) should I simply answer it myself with a message like "it must have been a fluke" and accept that or is there another way to close this more neatly?

Comment: I think its interesting to note that a question about email antispam gateways ends up on superuser.

Comment: I didn't add it here as it was not related to my question, but I am using Drupal, so it doesn't fit Stack Overflow and setting up a website on a shared hosting doesn't qualify it for Server Fault, so while Super User is not a truly good fit, it is the best fit.

Comment: it wasn't a good fit and was closed as off-topic: http://superuser.com/questions/132668/why-is-my-drupal-registration-email-considered-spam-by-gmail-headers-included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flag for moderation attention and ask for it to be closed as no longer relevant.

I believe that you can delete your question if it really has **no** value at all.

Comment: You can't delete your own question if it has answers or upvotes.

Comment: @ChrisF: one can only hope that an off-topic question would at least not get upvoted, and for what is written on this question, it seems plausible that he had no answers.

Comment: Someone did take a guess at the cause before I found out that it just didn't happen...

Comment: Oh and since then (I did add the fact the question was false to my question), someone did start ranting about how it was strange that I expected the email not to be identified as spam - and talked about some system you can use to identify your mail server and thus get your emails not classified as spam.